# nginx deny location access in location which is proxy passed to upstream

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, proxypass

I've got a Nginx server configuration like this:

```
location / {
                proxy_pass http://backend/;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forward-Proto http;
                proxy_set_header X-Nginx-Proxy true;

                proxy_redirect off;
                limit_except GET POST{
                        deny all;
                }
        }
```

and I'd like to deny any access to URL like `/path/subpath`. I tried to make it with nested location like:

```
location / {
    ....
    location ^~ /path/subpath {
        deny all; # another option is return 403/404
    }
}
```

But it does not work. Also tried the deny part outside of the root location part. Still, Nginx exactly redirect to any request to directly upstream and ignore settings inside the conf.

What I'm missing?

Comment: Regarding: "Also tried the deny part outside of the root location part." Did you put it before the "/" directive?

Comment: Yeap, i tried it before and after.

Comment: Also with a plain directive? I mean w/o any modifiers (^~), just location /path/subpath?

Comment: Yeah, tried that too. I can not get it.

Comment: Try adding an "allow" statement before the deny (even if the allow IP/network is nonsense). Which Nginx version btw?

Comment: Show full server block